# Unknown moving objects

Tags: photography, satellite, flare

Last night, I used my new Sony WX500 camera to get long exposure pictures of the sky from my backyard.  I used the "Heavens Above" app to find out when satellite flares would happen and I even got a great picture of the ISS passing overhead at roughly -2mag.  I was able to identify many flares that I had gotten pictures of when reviewing the pictures today.  However, this is where it gets odd.

Some moving "things" didn't match what was supposed to show according to the app.  Some were accidentally caught in the pictures I took, and I'm sure there aren't any flares that the app showed me.

What could they be?  Shooting stars?  Forgotten or broken satellites?

Comment: Check http://www.amsmeteors.org/fireballs/fireball-report/

Comment: Aircraft lights (but only if non-blinking); genuine satellites/old launch stages not in the database; random ("sporadic") meteors not part of an established shower; birds (yes, sometimes light-coloured migrating birds reflect city light from their bellies). Also, you might like to mail Heavens Above and ask them for an opinion on how complete the database is.

Comment: Adding some of these pictures to your post would help...

Comment: I like how Andy submitted that as a comment, not an answer.  No upvotes for answers!  Answer it the appropriate way might be useful next time...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Star like light moving in the sky, what could it be?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/11634/star-like-light-moving-in-the-sky-what-could-it-be)

Comment: J. Chomel  How many years did this conclusion take you to reach?  Please consider that hundreds have viewed this and no one else thinks it’s a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Converting comment to community wiki*

Possibilities:

- Aircraft lights (but only if non-blinking);
- genuine satellites/old launch stages not in the database;
- random ("sporadic") meteors not part of an established shower;
- birds (yes, sometimes light-coloured migrating birds reflect city light from their bellies).