# Confusing satellite-like object seen in night sky

Tags: satellite

I was staring up at the stars around 11:30 PM and noticed an object moving. It had no lights, and was not bright whatsoever. It was moving smoothly and in a straight line, except extremely fast, and dead silent. It was fairly large too, compared to how big stars look. Never would have noticed it had I not been looking at that particular region of the sky at the exact moment I did. It had to have crossed the sky in less than a minute. In fact, I feel like I've seen this same kind of thing once or twice before.

My question is what did I see? The fact that it was extremely dim, extremely fast, and produced no sound really confuse me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unknown moving objects](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/14406/unknown-moving-objects)

Comment: also related https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/11634/star-like-light-moving-in-the-sky-what-could-it-be

Comment: Was the object point-like? I don't understand how a point can be "not bright" and "fairly large", as "big" stars only differ from small ones in brightness.

Comment: Blimps can move fairly quickly. Usually have running lights though. Are you in an area they frequent?

Answer (score 1):

At first blush, this sounds like it was a large, low-Earth orbiting satellite, like the ISS for example. Depending upon the angle above the horizon the transit time could be very low s you described. Your position would determine whether the satellite was illuminated by the Sun or not at that local time.

Answer (score 0):

My guess, as @Tim said, is the ISS. I've seen it a few times, and it looks exactly as you've described. There are a few websites and mobile apps that can inform you of any satellites that are passing over your position; my go-to is [heavens-above.com](http://heavens-above.com/).