# What was that object?

Tags: amateur-observing

On July 13, 2018, just after the clouds had lost their color, a bright object became visible about 20 degrees above the western horizon (there was a hill).
It moved slowly east and had colors similar to what the clouds had recently.
In my spotting scope it was circular, sort of looked like the ring nebula, with an apparent diameter bigger than Jupiter.
It wasn't a satellite, nor an airplane. Weather balloon? Any ideas?
I know this isn't exactly an astronomy question, but I couldn't find another forum interested in such phenomina.

Comment: What's the location?

Comment: @StephenG I think the best unknown object identification request question should be found, and then the others could be closed as its dupe. I think [this](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/11634/1891) is the best. I think it would be the most welcoming way to handle these not really answerable questions.

Comment: Round, lit up like the clouds but higher so lit up longer, definitely sounds like a weather balloon.