# Orange light in sky

Tags: planet, night-sky

It is 1:15 am, 8/10/18 in Indiana. I looked out my kitchen window and saw an orange light to the north with the color of a street light but clearly out in space.  It was about as high as a full moon at 10pm in July. It must be a planet... Anybody know which one? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Why would you think it was "close".   Are you sure of your directions? Mars is orange, bright, about has high as the full moon in July and due *South* at the moment.  Also cut the bit about UFOs from your question, which makes you sound flaky.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Star like light moving in the sky, what could it be?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/11634/star-like-light-moving-in-the-sky-what-could-it-be)

Comment: Question gives useful information, acknowledges that a planet is most likely, and doesn't mention motion. Voting to leave open.

Comment: When I see big and orange I immediately think of smoke in the atmosphere. NOAA has smoke maps under the "air quality" tab at http://www.nws.noaa.gov/radar_tab.php There are a **lot** of fires burning this year.

Comment: Many people (non-astronomers) use "big" and "close" when they really mean "bright". As James K indicated, Mars is the likely answer if we assume the object was south (where the Moon would be from the U.S.A. state of Indiana).

Answer (score 1):

Most likely it was Mars, which was in the southern Indiana sky at the time you indicated.  I'm not aware of anything bright and orange in the northern sky that would have had a high altitude.