# i’ve seen an orange, slow blinking object in the sky

Tags: light, night-sky

it’s new year’s day and people are setting off fireworks and it’s a fairly clear sky tonight, and a weird orange slow blinking light was going eastwards. it wasn’t fast enough to be a plane, and i am kinda confused on what it is. i was just outside of glasgow and facing northwest when this happened

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Orange light in sky](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/27297/orange-light-in-sky)

Comment: Astronomical objects cant be described as "slow blinking" sio this is not a question about astronomy

Comment: but anyway, probably a drone (to take photos of the fireworks) or lantern (rotating in the wind).