# What were these lights in a line in the sky?

Tags: night-sky

Hello dear astronomy community,

On September 7 at 8:00pm me and my friend were hiking towards the Hollywood sign. We noticed roughly 10-15 bright lights moving in a line on the sky. That was very confusing to me, as I've never seen that before. They were due North East from us. [As per this question](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/11634/star-like-light-moving-in-the-sky-what-could-it-be), it was most certainly an artificial satellite. But is it possible to find out which organization launched them?

I tried looking here https://www.rocketlaunch.live/?pastOnly=1. No launches at that time.

Thanks!

Comment: Most likely a StarLink train. They are launched in groups of 50–60 then slowly move apart from each other.

Comment: "roughly 10-15 bright lights moving in a line on the sky" = starlink