# Sequence of starlike objects in the sky. What are they?

Tags: amateur-observing

Tonight me and some family members saw a sequence of starlike objects moving slowly in a straight line in the night sky. As they moved, they became sparser and began disappearing (front ones first). A family member took a couple of (terrible resolution) pictures. **What could they have been?**

According to [this post](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/22857/54330), their description fits that of artificial satellites or a space station, but what explains that they were multiple, not a single, starlike objects?

[image]

[image]

Comment: it's starlink. it's always starlink.

Comment: @AaronF soon I think we may need a close reason for “its starlink”